# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE, expecting T_FUNCTION in /home/petit/public_html/system/database/mysqli.php on line 54

Tags: php, mysqli

I have made an opencart transfer from a server to another and i am getting the following error 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE, expecting T_FUNCTION in /home/petit/public_html/system/database/mysqli.php on line 54

when i try to access my site or my administrator page.
Any idea why this is happening?
I have followed the procedure step by step.

**This is mysqli.php**

```
 <?php
final class MySQLi {
    private $mysqli;

    public function __construct($hostname, $username, $password, $database) {
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

        if ($this->mysqli->connect_error) {
            trigger_error('Error: Could not make a database link (' . $this->mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $this->mysqli->connect_error);
        }

        $this->mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        $this->mysqli->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
        $this->mysqli->query("SET CHARACTER_SET_CONNECTION=utf8");
        $this->mysqli->query("SET SQL_MODE = ''");
    }

    public function query($sql) {
        $result = $this->mysqli->query($sql);



        if ($this->mysqli->errno) {
        //$mysqli->errno
        }

            if (is_resource($resource)) {
                $i = 0;

                $data = array();

                while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
                    $data[$i] = $row;

                    $i++;
                }

                $result->close();

                $query = new stdClass();
                $query->row = isset($data[0]) ? $data[0] : array();
                $query->rows = $data;
                $query->num_rows = $result->num_rows;

                unset($data);




                return $query;  
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            trigger_error('Error: ' . mysql_error($this->link) . '<br />Error No: ' . mysql_errno($this->link) . '<br />' . $sql);
            exit();
        }
    }

    public function escape($value) {
        return $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($value);
    }

    public function countAffected() {
        return $this->mysqli->affected_rows;
    }

    public function getLastId() {
        return $this->mysqli->insert_id;
    }   

    public function __destruct() {
        $this->mysqli->close();
    }
}
?>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Use an IDE to match `{` curly `}` braces, use a different indentation style.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

there is `else` without `if`. the `if` block is closed. do it like -

```
if ($this->mysqli->errno) {
//$mysqli->errno

    if (is_resource($resource)) {
        $i = 0;

        $data = array();

        while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
            $data[$i] = $row;

            $i++;
        }

        $result->close();

        $query = new stdClass();
        $query->row = isset($data[0]) ? $data[0] : array();
        $query->rows = $data;
        $query->num_rows = $result->num_rows;

        unset($data);




        return $query;  
    } else {
        return true;
    }
} else {
    trigger_error('Error: ' . mysql_error($this->link) . '<br />Error No: ' . mysql_errno($this->link) . '<br />' . $sql);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: welcome...and please accept the answer if it is solved.